# Maven build takes too long

Tags: java, angular, maven, gitlab, pipeline

We have an angular+java app but
`mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -P prod`
takes too long.

I have also tried xms and xmx config to increase ram and also -T option for running on multiple threads

none had an effect

can anyone help?

Comment: maybe share your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: How does your gitlab pipeline looks like? Do you cache your maven artifacts during the builds? What means "long"?

Comment: Please include mvn output in the question.

Comment: Where is the time spent?

Comment: well the pipeline usually take s around 30 mins and most of time goes to downloading npm dependencies from nexus i have also tried increasing `--max_old_space_size` in my package.json but it had no effect

Comment: Does this happen locally or in a CI/CD pipeline? What about reusing/caching the downloaded npm dependencies?

Comment: in a gitlab cicd pipeline and i really dont want to use the caching method(maybe ill use it as a last resort)

Comment: If the time is spent downloading from nexus perhaps the bottleneck is there?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i have studied the logs closely and i found out that after npm install is run the, npm downloads node installation files from the internet rather than my nexus repo.in the log it also says : `[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly`